# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DemoApplication

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I created a new Spring application from https://start.srping.io

My `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '19'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

File `DemoApplication.java`

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[image]
I press button Run, the program error. How to fix it?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't do anything with the gradle file. So you probably need to run it through maven.

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like project dependencies mentioned in `build.gradle`  file not downloaded properly because I can see some compilation errors as well.

Please run this command and try again.

`gradle build`